# WooCommerce: Bulk Quantity in Cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I run a WooCommerce store with three types of packaging; sold individually, sold in bulk of 6 and sold in bulk of 12. These packagings are tagged by a taxonomy called criteria with the terms 6-pack and 12-pack.

With the code below, which I have in functions.php, the quantity steps on the bulk products are increased by 6 or 12. So far everything works just as planned.

The problem: when going to the cart page the quantity steps doesn’t work. That means that suddenly the steps for any product is 1, which means that a customer can change 12 to 13 instead of 24, etc.

Any ideas on how to keep the quantity steps on the cart page as well?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'input_set_all_values', 1, 2 );

function input_set_all_values( $args, $product ) { 
    if (( has_term('6-pack', 'criteria' ) ) ) {
    $args['step'] = 6;
    $args['min_value'] = 6;
    return $args;
    }
if (( has_term('12-pack', 'criteria' ) ) ) {
    $args['step'] = 12;
    $args['min_value'] = 12;
    return $args;
    }
else {
    $args['step'] = 1;
    $args['min_value'] = 1;
    return $args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you add `is_singular( 'product' )` ? Remove it!

Comment: I removed it but unfortunately it didn’t do the trick.

Comment: Please edit your question with updated code!

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.

Comment: I realize that I have a follow up question to this (not sure if I should add this to my original question?). The solution to add $product->post worked on product page and in cart, but is it possible to add 6 or 12 when clicking on the add to cart button in the store listing?

Comment: Yes it is possible. When there is add to cart request there is filter to modify the quantity of products as well. But you may ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is on cart page `has_term` is `false` because it is checking if cart page have terms `12-pack` or `6-pack`. You also need to provide post object/ID to [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) as a third parameter.

Updated code:-

```
function input_set_all_values( $args, $product ) { 
    if (( has_term('6-pack', 'criteria', $product->post ) ) ) {
        $args['step'] = 6;
        $args['min_value'] = 6;
        return $args;
    } else if (( has_term('12-pack', 'criteria', $product->post ) ) ) {
        $args['step'] = 12;
        $args['min_value'] = 12;
        return $args;
    } else {
        $args['step'] = 1;
        $args['min_value'] = 1;
        return $args;
    }
}
```